# How to add custom admin layout to show iFrame in Mageno 2

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml

I have created a custom module and trying to show the iframe in admin area.

Created a new action and able to access the url in browser.

Layout look like

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/layout/VENDOR_MODULE_registration_index.xml

Template look like

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/templates/test.phtml (it contain
>   the iframe as `<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>`)

I have tried

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="One" template="VENDOR_MODULE::test.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

OR

```
<body>
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="One" template="VENDOR_MODULE::test.phtml" />
    </container>
</body>
```

But the custom phtml file does not render on the browser?

How to set custom HTML content/iFrame in the admin area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debug it more and found that the layout file name is wrong. The correct file should be

```
FRONTNAME_registration_index.xml
```

frontName is defined in `routes.xml`.